If Julia does not tell apart object from non object, why functions do not mutate scalars?
In Julia manual types, it is said

There is no division between object and non-object values: all values in Julia are true objects having a type that belongs to a single, fully connected type graph, all nodes of which are equally first-class as types.

But a function cannot mutate basic data types like Floats or bolleans, but it can change an array. Why is this? How it differentiate these types?

I'm not sure about Julia, but in other OO languages it's simply that immutable types simply do not offer any methods of muting an instance. The object simply doesn't have any method you could call that would result in the object to change.

I believe you are misreading the statement. The passage you quote from the manual basically says, "There is no such thing as a non-object value in Julia."  Therefore it does not make sense to talk about "basic data types" like Bool and Float64 as being a part of some other kind of type system that acts differently from the type system governing things like Array. They are all part of the same type system.
What might be confusing you is the concept of mutability. You can read about mutable types in the same manual page that you quote, just a little further down. Values of immutable type cannot be changed, while values of mutable type can. You can check if a type is mutable using the ismutabletype method:
@assert ismutabletype(Float64) == false
@assert ismutabletype(Array) == true

You can also check if a value is of a mutable type with the ismutable method:
x = Float64(1.0)
@assert typeof(x) == Float64
@assert ismutable(x) == false

A = Float64[1.0, 2.0]
@assert typeof(A) == Array{Float64, 1}  # or Vector{Float64}
@assert ismutable(A) == true

So, to answer your first question, the types Bool and Float64 are "immutable" types, while Array is a "mutable" type. Julia does not know that a Float64 value is somehow a "basic data type" and an Array value is not: it knows that Float64 values are immutable and Array values are mutable.
It is the mutability property that allows functions to change the value associate with a variable. To demonstrate that this has nothing to do with "basic data types" versus other types, here is an example of two very similar struct definitions, one defined as mutable struct and one defined as a plain old (immutable) struct:
mutable struct MuS
    value::Int64
end

struct ImS
    value::Int64
end

This is a function that increments the value field of whatever variable you pass to it:
function increment!(x)
    x.value += 1
end

We can increment the value field of a MuS object because it was defined as mutable:
m = MuS(1)
increment!(m)
@assert m.value == 2

However, if we try the same with a ImS object:
i = ImS(1)
increment!(i)  # ERROR: setfield!: immutable struct of type ImS cannot be changed

And to answer your second question, it perhaps goes without saying that Julia can differentiate between these and all other types because, well, by definition they are different:
@assert Float64 != Array

